# KeyValueStore.get() returns inconsistent results

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

`stateStore.get()` returns inconsistent results, when used from `transform()` on `KStream`. It returns null, even though corresponding key-value has been `put()` into the store.

Can someone explain this behavior of `KeyValueStore<>`?

```
@Component
public class StreamProcessor {

    @StreamListener
    public void process(@Input(KStreamBindings.INPUT_STREAM) KStream<String, JsonNode> inputStream) {
        KStream<String, JsonNode> joinedEvents = inputStream
           .selectKey((key, value) -> computeKey(value))
           .transform(
               () -> new SelfJoinTransformer((v1, v2) -> join(v1, v2), "join_store"),
               "join_store"
            );
        
        joinedEvents
               .foreach((key, value) -> System.out.format("%s,joined=%b\n",key, value.has("right")));
    }

    private JsonNode join(JsonNode left, JsonNode right) {
        ((ObjectNode) left).set("right", right);
        return left;
    }
}

public class SelfJoinTransformer implements Transformer<String, JsonNode, KeyValue<String, JsonNode>> {
  private KeyValueStore<String, JsonNode> stateStore;
  private ValueJoiner<JsonNode, JsonNode, JsonNode> valueJoiner;
  private String storeName;

  public SelfJoinTransformer(ValueJoiner<JsonNode, JsonNode, JsonNode> valueJoiner, String storeName) {
    this.storeName = storeName;
    this.valueJoiner = valueJoiner;
  }

  @Override
  public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
     this.stateStore = (KeyValueStore<String, JsonNode>) context.getStateStore(storeName);
  }

  @Override
  public KeyValue<String, JsonNode> transform(String key, JsonNode value) {
    JsonNode oldValue = stateStore.get(key);
    if (oldValue != null) { //this condition rarely holds true
        stateStore.delete(key);
        System.out.format("%s,joined\n", key);
        return KeyValue.pair(key, valueJoiner.apply(oldValue, value));
    }
    stateStore.put(key, value);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add sample message flow, when and what happens?

Comment: Do you change the key using some `KStream::map` before calling transform(...)?

Comment: Used selectKey() just before calling transform

Comment: @BartoszWardziński I'll add the flow, shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason, that it seems messages are disappearing (assuming, that punctuator doesn't remove them) is that you use KStream::selectKey(...), it change key, but doesn't do repartitioning
And you might look for the key in wrong partitions.

Look at following scenarion:

- Msg1: `k1`, `v1` (`partition0`)
- Msg2: `k2`, `v2` (`partition1`)

Assumption messages are put in different partition (because of key)
After selectKey: `k1 -> k`, `k2 -> k`

- Msg1: `k`, `v1`
- Msg2: `k`, `v2`

Operation `selectKey` is stateless so messages are not sent to downstream (topic) and repartition doesn't happen.
For first message: value is put for key - k in the store (partition0)
When second message arrives: for key - k there is no message, because it is different partition (partition1)

Comment: I too have a similar situation. I'm trying to filter duplicate messages (based on some field in a message) and using state store for that. But it is returning inconsistent result with multiple partitions. How to resolve that issues?
This is my example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091713/7155432